# APACHE HIVE UDF's

Tags: java, hive

```
    package hive.analytics;    
public class FirstUpper extends UDF {

    public Text evaulate(Text actualName) throws IOException{
        String name = actualName.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String fc = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        String rc = name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        String res = fc + rc;       
        return new Text(res);       
    }
}
```

and I followed the below steps ..

```
add jar /home/chenna/Desktop/HiveApp1.jar;

create temporary function fupper
     as 'hive.analytics.FirstUpper';
```

**Query**

```
select fupper(name) from emp;
```

**Error**

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments 'name': No matching method for class hive.analytics.FirstUpper with (string). Possible choices:
```

Comment: Can you please some one suggest me on this !!!

Comment: can you paste the whole stackstrace?

Comment: should it be `String actualName`

Comment: try to test your UDF with constant argument, e.g. `select fupper('test')`. Plus before calling `actualName.toString()` it's better to check if `actualName` is null or not, otherwise you will get `NullPointerException` when argument's value is `NULL`.

Comment: another thing, can you post the full list of imports?

Comment: Gaurang Shah, thanks for the help... even i tried to give String actualName, but i got the same error ...  
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments 'name': No matching method for class hive.analytics.FirstUpper with (string). Possible choices:
and this is the whole stackstrace